# RecycleView update dataset and adapter from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm on a fragment activity that have 3 fragments. each fragments implement Recycle-view and it's adapter. I wanna delete from a list and then update another fragment lists but I have problem in this.

```
 public void deleteIt(View v) {

        ZeroActivity.dao.deleteMessages(serverId); // delete the mesage from DB
        switch (TransactionActivity.current_tab) {
            case 0:
                ZeroActivity.itemData_1.remove(data_list_position); // delete the message from arrayList
                ZeroActivity.recycleViewAdapter1.notifyItemRemoved(data_list_position); //remove message from Adapter
                break;
            case 2:
```

but always after first deletion and select final item app crashes and get this error:

```
Invalid index 4, size is 3
```

It seems that problem is with index of Adapter and Arraylist that wont match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem by refresh Recycle-view item counts by adding:

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(data_list_position, newsize);
```

it seems that Recycle-view needs to update it's list count after remove or adding new items.

```
       ZeroActivity.itemData_1.remove(data_list_position); // delete the message from arrayList
       ZeroActivity.recycleViewAdapter1.notifyItemRemoved(data_list_position); //remove message from Adsapter
       ZeroActivity.recycleViewAdapter1.notifyItemRangeChanged(data_list_position, ZeroActivity.itemData_1.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing two times with same index value thats why you are getting error in second time.. just do this . i hope it will work

```
ZeroActivity.itemData_1.remove(data_list_position); // delete the message from arrayList
ZeroActivity.recycleViewAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or call only this line

```
ZeroActivity.recycleViewAdapter1.notifyItemRemoved(data_list_position)
```

Comment: I wanna not only remove from RecycleView but also from my RecycleView  ArrayList.